# Sized delimiters (\left( \right)) are too tall for vertically aligned array (\begin{array}[t])

Tags: vertical-alignment, arrays, delimiters

Please compile the below and the problem will be clear.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent Compare
\[
\begin{array}{l}
  \land ~a\\
  \land \left(
    \begin{array}[t]{l}
      \lor ~a\\
      \lor \left(
        \begin{array}[t]{l}
          \land ~a\\
          \land ~b\\
        \end{array}
      \right)
    \end{array}
  \right)\\
\end{array}
\]
with
\[
\begin{array}{l}
  \land ~a\\
  \land
    \begin{array}[t]{l}
      \lor ~a\\
      \lor
        \begin{array}[t]{l}
          \land ~a\\
          \land ~b\\
        \end{array}
    \end{array}
\end{array}
.\]
I also don't want
\[
\begin{array}{l}
  \land ~a\\
  \land \left(
    \begin{array}{l}
      \lor ~a\\
      \lor \left(
        \begin{array}{l}
          \land ~a\\
          \land ~b\\
        \end{array}
      \right)
    \end{array}
  \right)\\
\end{array}
,\]
although it's better than the first version.
\end{document}
```

I want the vertical layout in the second version, but with parentheses around the nested subformulas.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is reasonably close, the spacing can be tweaked a bit, depending on what you need, this is just the default spacing from the package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{delarray}
\begin{document}
\noindent Compare
\[
\begin{array}{ll}
  \land &a\\
  \land&\begin{array}[t]({ll})
           \lor &a\\
            \lor &
           \begin{array}[t]({ll})
              \land&a\\
               \land&b
           \end{array}
\end{array}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! This `delarray` package looks perfect.